# Python networkx, plotly. How to display Edges mouse-over text

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, mouseover, edges

I need to display text when mouse is over edges (similar to image).
Maybe someone knows how to do it?
I took the example from [plotly.com](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/) and trying to modify it.
It fine works for Nodes, but I can not do it for Edges.
[image]

```py
import networkx
import plotly.graph_objects as go

G = networkx.random_geometric_graph(n=3, radius=1)

# Create Edges
edge_x, edge_y = [], []
for idx0, idx1 in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[idx0]["pos"]
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[idx1]["pos"]
    edge_x.extend([x0, x1, None])
    edge_y.extend([y0, y1, None])

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y, line=dict(width=10, color='#888'), mode='lines',
    hoverinfo='text',  # TODO, NOT WORKING
)
# TODO, NOT WORKING
edge_trace.text = [f"# {s}" for s in edge_x]

# Create Nodes with TEXT
node_x = []
node_y = []
nodes_o = G.nodes
nodes_ids = list(nodes_o)
for node in nodes_ids:
    x, y = G.nodes[node]["pos"]
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(x=node_x, y=node_y, mode="markers", hoverinfo="text",
                        marker=dict(color=[], size=50, line_width=10))
node_trace.text = [f"TEXT{idx}" for idx, _ in G.adjacency()]

# Create Network Graph
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
    layout=go.Layout(),
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Plotly doesn't actually have any functionality that will account for hover content over the length of a line. However, you can use a workaround.

You could plot transparent points at the midpoint of each edge. Alternatively, you could plot any number of transparent points on each edge.

##### Just the midpoint

When you create the edge data, you can add the code to create the midpoints, as well.

```
mnode_x, mnode_y, mnode_txt = [], [], []
edge_x, edge_y = [], []
for idx0, idx1 in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[idx0]["pos"]
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[idx1]["pos"]
    edge_x.extend([x0, x1, None])
    edge_y.extend([y0, y1, None])

    mnode_x.extend([(x0 + x1)/2]) # assuming values positive/get midpoint
    mnode_y.extend([(y0 + y1)/2]) # assumes positive vals/get midpoint
    mnode_txt.extend([f"# {x0}"]) # hovertext
```

Then create the trace for these points, setting the opacity to 0 so the points aren't actually visible.

```
mnode_trace = go.Scatter(x = mnode_x, y = mnode_y, mode = "markers", showlegend = False,
                         hovertemplate = "Edge %{hovertext}<extra></extra>",
                         hovertext = mnode_txt, marker = go.Marker(opacity = 0))
```

Lastly, when you assemble your figure, add this trace, as well.

```
# Create Network Graph
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[edge_trace, node_trace, mnode_trace],
    layout=go.Layout())
```

[image]

##### You designate how many points per edge

If you wanted to have a quantity that you specify of points on each edge, you could use this instead. These two functions work together to create the midpoints of line segments within line segments.

This requires `deque` from the `collections` package.

```
import networkx
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from collections import deque 

def queue(a, b, qty):
    """either x0 and x1 or y0 and y1, qty of points to create"""
    q = deque()
    q.append((0, qty - 1)) # indexing starts at 0
    pts = [0] * qty
    pts[0] = a; pts[-1] = b # x0 is the first value, x1 is the last
    while len(q) != 0:
        left, right = q.popleft()       # remove working segment from queue
        center = (left + right + 1)//2  # creates index values for pts
        pts[center] = (pts[left] + pts[right])/2
        if right - left > 2:            # stop when qty met
            q.append((left, center))
            q.append((center, right))
    return pts


def collector(x0, x1, y0, y1, qty, ht):
    """line segment end points, how many midpoints, hovertext"""
    pth = [ht] * qty
    ptx = queue(x0, x1, qty + 2) # add 2 because the origin will be in the list
    pty = queue(y0, y1, qty + 2)
    ptx.pop(0); ptx.pop()        # pop first and last (the nodes)
    pty.pop(0); pty.pop()        # pop first and last (the nodes)
    return ptx, pty, pth
```

Then, like the 'just the midpoint', you can send the line segment ends to `collector` from the call to create the edge data.

```
# Create Edges
m2x, m2y, m2t = [], [], []
edge_x, edge_y = [], []
for idx0, idx1 in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[idx0]["pos"]
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[idx1]["pos"]
    edge_x.extend([x0, x1, None])
    edge_y.extend([y0, y1, None])

    # the 3 is points per line; x0 at the end is for hovertext
    ptsx, ptsy, ptsh = collector(x0, x1, y0, y1, 3, x0)
    m2x.extend(ptsx)
    m2y.extend(ptsy)
    m2t.extend(ptsh)
```

Finally, create the trace and combine the figure.

```
m2node_trace = go.Scatter(x = m2x, y = m2y, mode = "markers", showlegend = False,
                          hovertemplate = "Edge # %{hovertext}<extra></extra>",
                          hovertext = m2t, marker = go.Marker(opacity = 0))

fig2 = go.Figure(data = [edge_trace, node_trace, m2node_trace],
                 layout = go.Layout())
```

I added a `<br>` to this plot's `hovertext` for differentiation.

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank You so much for such a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a fully working example based on [Kat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329073/kat) approach.
[image]

```py
from collections import deque

import networkx
import plotly.graph_objects as go

EDGE_POINTS_QUANTITY = 20
EDGE_POINTS_OPACITY = 1
EDGES = 3


def queue(a, b, qty):
    """either x0 and x1 or y0 and y1, qty of points to create"""
    q = deque()
    q.append((0, qty - 1))  # indexing starts at 0
    pts = [0] * qty
    pts[0] = a
    pts[-1] = b  # x0 is the first value, x1 is the last
    while len(q) != 0:
        left, right = q.popleft()  # remove working segment from queue
        center = (left + right + 1) // 2  # creates index values for pts
        pts[center] = (pts[left] + pts[right]) / 2
        if right - left > 2:  # stop when qty met
            q.append((left, center))
            q.append((center, right))
    return pts


def make_middle_points(first_x, last_x, first_y, last_y, qty):
    """line segment end points, how many midpoints, hovertext"""
    # Add 2 because the origin will be in the list, pop first and last (the nodes)
    middle_x_ = queue(first_x, last_x, qty + 2)
    middle_y_ = queue(first_y, last_y, qty + 2)
    middle_x_.pop(0)
    middle_x_.pop()
    middle_y_.pop(0)
    middle_y_.pop()
    return middle_x_, middle_y_


G = networkx.random_geometric_graph(n=EDGES, radius=1)

# Create Edges with TEXT
edge_x, edge_y = [], []
edge_middle_x, edge_middle_y, edge_middle_text = [], [], []
for idx0, idx1 in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[idx0]["pos"]
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[idx1]["pos"]
    edge_x.extend([x0, x1, None])
    edge_y.extend([y0, y1, None])

    # the 3 is points per line; x0 at the end is for hovertext
    middle_x, middle_y = make_middle_points(x0, x1, y0, y1, EDGE_POINTS_QUANTITY)
    edge_middle_x.extend(middle_x)
    edge_middle_y.extend(middle_y)
    edge_middle_text.extend([f"EDGE{idx0}{idx1}"] * EDGE_POINTS_QUANTITY)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(x=edge_x, y=edge_y, line=dict(width=10, color='#888'), mode='lines')
m2node_trace = go.Scatter(x=edge_middle_x, y=edge_middle_y, mode="markers", showlegend=False,
                          hovertemplate="Edge # %{hovertext}<extra></extra>",
                          hovertext=edge_middle_text,
                          marker=go.Marker(opacity=EDGE_POINTS_OPACITY))

# Create Nodes with TEXT
node_x = []
node_y = []
nodes_o = G.nodes
nodes_ids = list(nodes_o)
for node in nodes_ids:
    x, y = G.nodes[node]["pos"]
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(x=node_x, y=node_y, mode="markers", hoverinfo="text",
                        marker=dict(size=50, line_width=10))
node_trace.text = [f"NODE{idx}" for idx, _ in G.adjacency()]

# Create Network Graph
fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace, m2node_trace], layout=go.Layout())
fig.show()
```